# magento 2 | Categories not showing in Admin Product Edit Page

Tags: product, category, backend

I have started working with magento earlier this year, I am running magento CE 2.2.2

I have noticed that when I go back to edit a product from the catalog I have noticed that the categories are not listed.

I have checked the frontend and item visible in the category, the problem is in the backend, you can see the attachment image below.

**Does anyone encounter the problem or know a solution that can be applied?**

here you can see the categories I chose during product setup:
[image]
[image url](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yneohjmcq1w3uak/categories_before_saving.jpg?dl=0)

but it is showing like this when I go to edit, which makes it impossible to edit categories:
[image]
[image url](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d960rpyno5f0bx2/categories_after_saving.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: please try to add category after re-indexing

Comment: When I tried to add a product to a category, it showed fine but when I click save, it disappeared from the list. but the same thing when I went to the frontend I could see the item fine.

Comment: Hi Did you find the solution for this issue. I am also facing the same issue

Comment: @DalbinShimy no, unfortunately, I could not find a solution. to make it more complicated... I downloaded a backup on my local xampp server, and after running reindex command, everything worked fine. 

So then I thought that the problem is from the hosting, but my hoster told me that there is nothing wrong... Still not sure about this.

Comment: Hi Robert. Thanks for the reply. It is working fine in my local but not working in live or dev site.

Comment: I am still struggling to find a solution. I am thinking that it is some kind of permissions, but can't get exactly what is happening. If someone finds a solution I will appreciate it.

Comment: I had this happen to me - reindex - clear cache - flush cache should work

Comment: Hello dose anyone find the solution? I am having exactly same issue

Answer (score 0):

Solution is following sequence of commands:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/static/ app/etc/ pub/media/
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/static/ app/etc/ pub/media/
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I was able to resolve it by going to the admin > Systems > Cache Management and click on 'Flush Cache Storage'